# Sort a tensor and return the sorted index?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to sort a tensor on a specific dimension and return a tensor of the same dimension that specifies the sorted index of each element. It seems that tf.nn.top_k can return the sorted indices but how to I map it back?

```
input = [[10, 3, 1], [5, 6, 2], [1, 7, 10]]
_, indices = tf.nn.top_k(input, k=3, sorted=True)
indices = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]]
```

What I hope to get is

```
reordered = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Are you assuming that `k` is actually the width of your array?

Comment: Yes, so that I can get a tensor of the same shape as input to order all elements.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `indices` contains all indices, i.e. is a permutation of `range(k)`, you could use

```
tf.map_fn(tf.invert_permutation, indices)
```

(`tf.invert_permutation` works on 1D tensors, so you need to wrap it into a `map_fn` to apply it to each row of `indices`).